# In portfolio optimisation through CVXPY, How can I constraint the Maximum sector weight for the portfolio

Tags: python, optimization, portfolio, cvxpy

I have a portfolio, which I need to optimize in such a way that - maximum sector weight is constrained to 30%. That is - No sector can have more than 30% weight in portfolio.

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

np.random.seed(1)
mu = np.abs(np.random.randn(10, 1))
Sigma = np.random.randn(10, 10)
Sigma = Sigma.T.dot(Sigma)

w = cp.Variable(10)
sector = ['A','A','B','C','B','A','C','A','B','A']

gamma = cp.Parameter(nonneg=True)
ret = mu.T @ w
risk = cp.quad_form(w, Sigma)
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(ret - gamma * risk), [cp.sum(w) == 1, w >= 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to add the inequality constraint `a @ w <= b` with

```
a = np.array(
    [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
)
```

and `b = np.array([0.3, 0.3, 0.3])`

So your new problem becomes:

```
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(ret - gamma * risk), [cp.sum(w) == 1, w >= 0, a @ w <= b])
```

However, note that in this case, it is unfeasible because you have three sectors (A, B, and C) with a constraint of 30% on each. Therefore, the maximum portfolio weight would be 90%, which conflicts with the fully invested constraint `np.sum(w) == 1`.

The same can be achieved with the [skfolio](https://github.com/skfolio/skfolio) package (disclosure: I'm the author), which also uses CVXPY. I've changed the last sector weight to 40% to make it feasible:

```
from skfolio.datasets import load_sp500_dataset
from skfolio.optimization import MeanRisk, ObjectiveFunction
from skfolio.preprocessing import prices_to_returns

prices = load_sp500_dataset()
prices = prices.iloc[:, : 10]
X = prices_to_returns(prices)

groups = [['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A']]
linear_constraints = ["A <= 0.3", "B <= 0.3", "C <= 0.4"]

model = MeanRisk(
    objective_function=ObjectiveFunction.MAXIMIZE_UTILITY,
    risk_aversion=1.0,
    groups=groups,
    linear_constraints=linear_constraints
)
model.fit(X)
print(model.weights_)
```

A full example is available [here](https://skfolio.org/auto_examples/1_mean_risk/plot_5_weight_constraints.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-1-mean-risk-plot-5-weight-constraints-py)

Comment: Hi Hugo Delatte, welcome to SO. Full disclosure is expected when referencing a package you have authored. While your answer is IMO superb and your intentions are clearly genuine, undisclosed affiliation can result in answers being flagged for deletion. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) for more info. Thanks

Comment: Disclosure added, thanks for the SO best practices explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exact syntax for cvxpy but you'd need a constraint like
`w[s] <= 0.3`for all `s` where variable`w`is sector weight indexed over sector`s`. Alternately you can define upper bound of`w` vector as 0.3 (or 30) & put a sum constraint
`sum(w[s] over s) = 1 or 100`